# How redirect stderr to variable inside if condition? Bash

Tags: bash

I try get standard error communicate from `mkdir -p $FINAL_BACKUP_DIR` and send in message by `logger`.

It make log more complete for example the user will be know he do not have permission or `$FINAL_BACKUP_DIR` does not exists.

```
if ! mkdir -p $FINAL_BACKUP_DIR; then
    logger -t $LOGGER_TAG "Cannot create backup directory in $FINAL_BACKUP_DIR. Standard error communicate. Backup canceling." 1>&2
    exit 1;
fi;
```

I try something like that:

```
if ! mkdir -p $FINAL_BACKUP_DIR 2>> ${test1}; then
    logger -t $LOGGER_TAG "Cannot create backup directory in $FINAL_BACKUP_DIR. Backup canceling. $test1" 1>&2
    exit 1;
fi;
```

But this solution does not working for me in two ways. When I create `test1` earlier `test1=0` or without that.

I work with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you would want to do. You want to log (with `logger`) if the `mkdir` failed, and you also want to inform the user? What are you trying to do with `test1`?

Comment: Yes I want inform the user if cannot create directory and already I got that but I would inform the user why it is impossible. I would use stderr for this. For example 'Permission denied'.

Comment: I try redirect stderr from 'mkdir -p $FINAL_BACKUP_DIR' to 'test1' vairable and in next step - use this in string which should be send via 'logger'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/dev/null` is the standard device to "throw things away".

So

```
some_command 2> /dev/null
```

will send the errors from `some_command` to `/dev/null` - ie throw away the errors.

Thus:

```
if ! mkdir -p $FINAL_BACKUP_DIR 2> /dev/null
then
  logger -t $LOGGER_TAG "Cannot create backup directory in $FINAL_BACKUP_DIR. Backup canceling."
  exit 1
fi
```

Note that you also didn't need all those extra `;` characters :-)

EDIT:

You can also direct error to output and capture the result in a variable and test if that variable is empty.  In this way you can report on the reason to the user

```
result=$(mkdir -p $FINAL_BACKUP_DIR 2>&1)
if [ -n "$result" ]
then
  logger -t $LOGGER_TAG "Cannot create backup directory in $FINAL_BACKUP_DIR. Backup canceling: $result"
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if ! mkdir -p $FINAL_BACKUP_DIR > ${test1} 2>&1
then
    logger -t $LOGGER_TAG "Cannot create backup directory in $FINAL_BACKUP_DIR. Backup canceling. $(< ${test1})" 
    exit 1;
fi;
```

where

- `> ${test1}` redirect output (stdout)
- `2>&1` tell bash to merge stderr and stdout
- `$(< $test1)` read content of file `${test1}`
- you have to delete `${test1}`
- tested on ubuntu 15.X, with a valid `${test1}`

Comment: If you use this route then you should make sure that `$test1` is created securely (e.g don't just call it `/tmp/errfile`).  `mktemp` may be useful.  In general it's beneficial to avoid transient temporary files when they're not needed.

Comment: agreed, OP concern seems to be the redirection, I assume deleting file would be no problem.

Comment: @Archemar You solution was more suitable for me but still not working.Error ' ${test1}: ambiguous redirect'. I try  use double qoutes "${test1} " but 'No such file or directory' occurs. Anyway thank for answer which include new things for me :)

Comment: you have a valid test1 filename ? date > ${test1} is okay ?

Comment: It is already working for me, seems yesterday I had some small bug in script. Secondly I must have created 'test1' variable before 'if ! mkdir -p $FINAL_BACKUP_DIR > ${test1} 2>&1' . Maybe it is obvious but I am new in bash :) Thanks for help:)